# Get app purchase date for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 applications

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

Is there a way, either in C# or C++ APIs for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 Metro applications, to get the user's app purchase date or, in case the app has been downloaded for free, the date of the first download? I'm specifically talking about the application's purchase date, not IAPs.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's few options:

1) Check out [Windows.ApplicationModel.Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package) -class. It's available for 8.1 Store apps and provides information like [InstalledDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.installeddate#Windows_ApplicationModel_Package_InstalledDate). Word of warning, some of the properties only work in desktop apps.

2) You should be able to get the [app's receipt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp#Windows_ApplicationModel_Store_CurrentApp_GetAppReceiptAsync). [Receipt contains PurchaseDate for the product.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/use-receipts-to-verify-product-purchases)

3) Manual way: When the app launches for the first time, create a roaming setting / app data where you store the launch date.